# Override marionettejs render method to send airbrakes to airbrake.io

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, airbrake

I want to send airbrakes that arise due to rendering of a marionette view to airbrake.io
But i do not want to put try catch in all the methods of the view. Is there a better way to do it?

Current implementation:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (e) {
  Airbrake.push(error);
}
```

Comment: Are you only wanting to catch errors on render?

Comment: Yes among other things. Catching errors on window.error does not give a proper stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a mixin similar to this,

#### Define the mixin function

```
    var asAirBreakView = function () {
        //note, this function assumes it's being called using 'apply' or 'call'
        //so context could be set to view's prototype.              

        //store original render function
        var originalRender = this.render

        //replace the render function with the wrapped render function
        this.render = function () {
            try {
                //call original render function with arguments passed in
               return originalOnRender.apply(this, arguments);
            } catch (e) {
                Airbrake.push(error);
                throw e;
            }
        };
    };
```

#### Apply the mixin to your view

```
    var view =  Marionette.ItemView.extend({  
        //define your view here
    });

    //Apply the mixin to prototype of your view
    view = asAirBreakView.apply(view.prototype);
```

I really love how you can add behaviour to functions and classes in javascript. it's something you don't get in classic inheritance languages like C# or java.